# undefined method `react_component' on ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, reactjs, unicorn

I am using ReactJs with rails . i am using `react-rails` gem. Everything is working fine on local machine, but when deployed it on my ubuntu server, it produces `undefined method react_component` error. I try to run app locally on production mode everything works fine . On my production server i use Nginx with Unicorn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into my capistrano settings, i figure out my unicorn server is not restart after deployment. So i kill my unicorn process and deploy again and everything is working fine now.